# C Type for hold different types of function pointers

Tags: c, types

Given the following varibles

```
int *a = 0;
char *b = "string"
```

I can put them both into a `void *hold;`
I don't find the way for `function pointers.`

```
void (*hello)(char param1, char param2);
char (*another)();
```

Is it even possible to stock these `2 different types` into a general `one` such as void *? And then retrieve them with casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast function pointers to any other function pointer type and back. Just choose a target type like `void (*)(void)`. From the C99 standard:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.